# Change column value based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT fund.sak_fund_group || ' - ' || fund.dsc_fund_group AS FundCodeGrp, 
       fund.sak_fund_group AS SakFundCodeGrp, 
       xref.dte_effective AS EffectiveDate, 
       xref.dte_end AS EndDate,  
       xref.dte_last_update AS LastUpdateDate 
FROM   T_MC_RATE_CELL rate,
       T_MC_AID_GRP aid,
       T_FUND_CDE_GRP fund,
       T_MC_REGION region,
       T_MC_RATE_FUND_GRP_XREF xref
```

I am pulling data using above query. I need to change the data of FundCodeGrp based on EndDate. If enddate is **!=12/31/2299** i need to pass SakFundCodeGrp value from above query to below query to get new FundCodeGrp value and replace with old value.

```
SELECT sak_fund_group || ' - ' || dsc_fund_group as FundCodeGroup
from A_T_FUND_CDE_GRP
WHERE sak_fund_group = " + sakFundCode + " 
    and dsc_fund_group IS NOT NULL 
    and cde_action = 'U' 
    and rownum < 2 
order by Dte_Sysdate asc
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: The question would be clearer if the example used one table and two columns, and some sample data. e.g. I don't think `sac` or `rate.dsc_cap_category` are needed to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: purpose of order by in second query?

Comment: A_T_FUND_CDE_GRP and T_FUND_CDE_GRP are different table?

Comment: Gaj, yes both are different tables